# What is the difference between this two scenario in finding exactly-once duplicate in an array of integers?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have been doing an exercise of an introductory algorithm book, which provides me of an array of integers of length n, but the elements in it are ranged from 1 to n-1, there is one integer repeats exactly once in it. I need to find the duplicate element using a fast algorithm.

I used this solution here to solve this problem
   http://www.jasondavies.com/duplicates/
which used O(n) time and O(1) space.

I thought everything is ok, however, the question that follows this one in this book is quite similar, it was an array of integers of length n, but the elements in it are ranged from 1 to n-5, there are five integers that each repeats exactly once in this array.

I could not tell the nature of difference of these two scenarios, I would use the same solution above for these two questions. However, the author seems do not think so, in his hint for this later question, he suggests "sort this array first". I am confused here, could experts criticize on the validity of my proposed solution to these two different scenarios? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it possible to see the authors code?

Comment: big o of n is about as best as I can think of for something like that.

Comment: @jollarvia, the author does not provide a solution but hint. Here is the hint for this:http://higheredbcs.wiley.com/legacy/college/goodrich/0470398809/miss_fig/hints/C-3-4/C-3.4-hint.html

Comment: @jollarvia,the book is named "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java, 5th Edition", the author is Michael.T.GoodRich.

Comment: What do you mean by find the duplicates : find the values that are duplicated or find the positions of the duplicates ?

Comment: What do we need to do second problem ? Find all the duplicate elements?

Comment: How exactly would you use the same solution to find *all* duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

The most efficient sorting algorithm uses nlogn time. Then you add in the search, that's big Omega n so you could be potentially looking at a big O time n+nlogn which is clearly worse than your algorithm.

The flip side of this is that if you are looking for one half of your list and you just happen to know that they are all near the beginning of your list when it's sorted then sorting beforehand becomes more attractive.  lets compare them with k = number of elements to find in list, n = number of elements in list.

If k = 1, then doing your chosen algorithm you get k*n or just 1n.  each time you pass over an element in n, you have to check if anything in k matches it.  As k gets bigger though, you come into problems.  with k at 1/2n you get 1/2n*n which is already much worse than n+nlogn. And until you find that last element, you have to keep going until you find it, possibly to the end of the list.

Sorting it first you have options now. The least you have to find is x, the most is y.  So you can start searching in the middle of the list, is x smaller than the number in the middle? No? start your search from the middle of the list to the end, cutting your search potentially in half resulting in 1/2n+nlogn or better if you partition more.